# Power BI/DAX: Filter SUMMARIZE or GROUPBY by added column value

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, summarize

because of confidential nature of data, I'll try to describe what I'm struggling with using some random examples.
Let's say I have a fact table with invoices data in Power BI. I need to count number of distinct product ID's with sales over let's say €50k in last 12 months or to be more precise in 12 months prior selected date. At the same time I need to be able to narrow down results to selected Country, Product group and Product category.

I've started with setting the dates range for DATESBETWEEN like this:

```
productsCount = 
VAR lastDay = IF(MAX('Calendar table'[Date]) > NOW(); NOW(); MAX('Calendar table'[Date]))
VAR firstDay = EDATE(lastDay; -12)
RETURN
```

But then I got lost:

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Sales');
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Sales';
        'Sales'[ProductID];
        "prodSales"; SUM('Sales'[EUR])
    );
    DATESBETWEEN('Sales'[Date]; firstDay; lastDay);
    ALLEXCEPT(
        'Sales';
        'Sales'[Product group];
        'Sales'[Product category];
        'Sales'[Country]
    );
    [prodSales] > 50000
)
```

The thing is that I need to be able to filter summarized data by sum of sales before I'll count rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I think something like this might work where you filter after summarizing:

```
productsCount =
VAR lastDay =
    IF (
        MAX ( 'Calendar table'[Date] ) > NOW ();
        NOW ();
        MAX ( 'Calendar table'[Date] )
    )
VAR firstDay = EDATE ( lastDay; -12 )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                SUMMARIZE ( 'Sales';
                   'Sales'[ProductID];
                   "prodSales"; SUM ( 'Sales'[EUR] )
                );
                DATESBETWEEN ( 'Sales'[Date]; firstDay; lastDay );
                ALLEXCEPT (
                    'Sales';
                    'Sales'[Product group];
                    'Sales'[Product category];
                    'Sales'[Country]
                )
            );
            [prodSales] > 50000
        )
    )
```

Comment: I just needed to add few more filters to ALLEXCEPT (because of other visuals on the report page and crossfiltering capabilities) and it Works. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

In summarise, we can do filter after the summarize table

My input table is

[image]

I'm writing query

```
App Downlaod Count = 

FILTER(
    SUMMARIZE(events_intraday,
    events_intraday[event_name],
    events_intraday[event_date],
    events_intraday[platform],
    events_intraday[stream_id],
    "Count",CALCULATE(
        COUNT(events_intraday[event_name]),
            FILTER(events_intraday,
                    (events_intraday[platform] = "ANDROID" || 
                    events_intraday[platform] = "IOS")
                )
            )
        ),
        events_intraday[event_name] = "first_open" && 
        (events_intraday[stream_id] = "1415470954" || 
        events_intraday[stream_id] = "1420775080")
    )
```

Output is

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can create a summarized table in power query editor and then create a measure in dax to filter the result over 50k.

Comment: I don't see how can I prepare such table to be able to do what I need to.